# Custom Gesture on top on UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom gesture that fires if the user slides his or her finger down the side of the device. It works fine in isolation, however, I want it on top of a UITableView. Whenever I slide my finger down the side, the custom gesture is masked and instead the table view scrolls. I want the table view to scroll, but in addition to that, I also want the custom gesture to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to add an additional gesture recognizer to the tableview (Not overwrite existing behavior) there are relatively few hoops.

Set the delegate property of your custom recognizer to a class conforming to the `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` protocol.

Have that class implement the following method:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```

And the the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of your recognizer to `NO`.